# passing the parameter along with the url and getting the result back

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

Is it possible to get the result on calling a url and passing the respective parameters along with the url?

For example suppose I pass two nos along with the url and I get the sum back.

The sum is calculated in the called url page

Comment: Yes you can do it, if u wan to pass more than one parameter you have to specify in global.asax

Comment: thank you for replying back .Can you show me with example please??

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, data can be sent as URL variables. This is what happens when you use a form which is using "GET"

e.g.

https://www.google.co.uk/?q=example

you are passing "example" as the search term inside the URL

if you want to read up about it properly, have a read through this [Post on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data)